# sequences convergence in different topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In different topological spaces, sequential convergence can be really bizarre. The following are 6 examples:

1. $X$ is an uncountable set with the cofinite topology (in which the closed sets are $X$ and finite subsets of $X$).
2. $X$ is any uncountable set with co-countable topology, in which the closed sets are $X$ and all countable subsets of $X$.
3. $X$ is the real line with the topology in which the open sets are the sets of the form $(a,\infty), a \in \mathbf{R}$
4. $X$ is the sorgenfrey Line $\mathbf{E}$
5. $X$ is a discrete space.
6. $X$ is any trivial space.

**My question is, how to find/exhaust all convergent sequences? For 1,2, there is a complete answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3867100/549321). So we don't care about 1,2 here. We only discuss 3-6 here.**

For 3: I think for any $x \in X$, the convergent sequence to $x$ is any sequence that finally lies in $(x,\infty)$

For 4: We know the Sorgenfrey line $\mathbf{E}$ is finer than usual topology $\tau$ on $\mathbf{R}$. So sequences converging in $\mathbf{E}$ must also converge in  $\mathbf{R}$  . I only find from a lecture that: **"Decreasing sequences which are bounded below converge in the Sorgenfrey line"** However, is that all?

For 5: The only convergent sequence is eventually a constant sequence.

For 6: Any sequence is convergent to any point.

**Am I doing right in examples 3-6?**

Comment: $3$, $5$ and $6$ look good. For $4$, a sequence is convergent under the Sorgenfrey topology iff it converges "from the right" in the usual topology. I.e., $s_n \to x$ (for some $x$) under the usual topology and $s_n \ge x$ for all sufficiently large $n$) - this doesn't imply that $s_n$ is decreasing (so the condition you quote is sufficient but not necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about $3,5,6$, but for $3$ you'll need a small argument. And you have to be careful about how you state it: you want to characterise a sequence that converges to *some* point, and the characterisation would (IMO) not mention a limit at all. Just properties of the sequence.

For the Sorgenfrey line it's clear that if $(x_n)$ is Sorgenfrey convergent it is also Euclidean-convergent (to the same limit), and almost all terms lie on the right of that limit...